# Angular 2 - Typescript Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when I run ng-serve

Tags: git, angular, drag-and-drop

Here are my steps:

```
Install node latest v7
Install angular cli > npm install -g @angular/cli
Open CMD and via CMD navigate to Desktop > cd Desktop
Create an angular project via angular CLI > ng new testNg
Navigate to project > cd testing
Run ng serve to launch > ng serve ( response all good, page loaded)
Navigate to app to add the code from github > cd src/app
Clone from github using SSH into the app folder > git clone git@github.com:akserg/ng2-dnd.git
Run ng server to launch > ng serve ( errors)
Found out I had a missing typescript, so install typescript > npm install typescript –save
10.2 Added on type \Testing\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js on line 8735 console.log(fileName); - that is inside the createSourceFile function.
Found out that rxjs not installed > npm install rxjs –save
Ng serve> still error
Ng build > still error
```

Now that I got my new project set.

I got this Angular drag and drop library that is not build as node_mule. I want to setup what the user has in github.

if I do ng serve, everything compile and load perfectly.

**ng --version:**

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 7.7.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

So I do cd src/app
git clone git@github.com:akserg/ng2-dnd.git
A folder ng2-dnd is setup.

When I run ng server I keep getting this TypeScript error.

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescr
ipt\lib\typescript.js:8980:109)

I see that several people are having issue with this and can't seem how to get this working. Is it because it is set wrong, or missing a dependency. Any ideas anyone?

**Here is the full errro log**

```
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
fallbackLoader option has been deprecated - replace with "fallback"
loader option has been deprecated - replace with "use"
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescr
ipt\lib\typescript.js:8980:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\ty
pescript\lib\typescript.js:8940:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\t
ypescript\lib\typescript.js:8899:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\
typescript\lib\typescript.js:8727:29)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\nod
e_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\compiler_host.js:210:27)
    at findSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescrip
t\lib\typescript.js:45859:29)
    at processSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typesc
ript\lib\typescript.js:45790:27)
    at C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript
.js:45901:17
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescrip
t\lib\typescript.js:1115:30)
    at processReferencedFiles (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\t
ypescript\lib\typescript.js:45899:16)
    at findSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescrip
t\lib\typescript.js:45884:21)
    at processSourceFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typesc
ript\lib\typescript.js:45790:27)
    at processRootFile (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescri
pt\lib\typescript.js:45694:13)
    at C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript
.js:45151:60
    at Object.forEach (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typescrip
t\lib\typescript.js:1115:30)
    at Object.createProgram (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\typ
escript\lib\typescript.js:45151:16)
    at AotPlugin._setupOptions (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\
@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:124:28)
    at new AotPlugin (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\@ngtools\w
ebpack\src\plugin.js:23:14)
    at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_m
odules\angular-cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:26:13)
    at new NgCliWebpackConfig (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\a
ngular-cli\models\webpack-config.js:24:37)
    at Class.run (C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\angular-cli\ta
sks\serve.js:31:29)
    at C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serv
e.run.js:22:22
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing>
```

**Here are related links:**

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5132
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5053

**I've tried on OS and get an error also**

Here is what I got in my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "dnd-2.4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.0.0-rc.1.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  },
   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Here is what I get in my Terminal:**
Here are the command I later on this day on my OS

```
 npm init
 npm uninstall -g angular-cli
 npm uninstall angular-cli
 npm uninstall angular-cli@1.0.0-rc.1
 npm cache clean
 npm  install angular-cli@1.0.0-rc.0
ng --version
```

**How to downgrade to @angular/core: 2.4.8 ?**

```
   Chriss-iMac:dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1 christarasovs$ ng --version
    Your global Angular CLI version (1.0.0-rc.1) is greater than your local
    version (1.0.0-rc.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

    To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
        _                      _                 ____ _     ___
       / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
      / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
     / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
    /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                   |___/
    @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
    node: 7.7.1
    os: darwin x64
    @angular/common: 2.4.9
    @angular/compiler: 2.4.9
    @angular/core: 2.4.9
    @angular/forms: 2.4.9
    @angular/http: 2.4.9
    @angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
    @angular/router: 3.4.9
    @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0
    @angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9



Chriss-iMac:dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1 christarasovs$ ng serve
Your global Angular CLI version (1.0.0-rc.1) is greater than your local
version (1.0.0-rc.0). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at createSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8980:109)
    at parseSourceFileWorker (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8940:26)
    at Object.parseSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8899:26)
    at Object.createSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:8727:29)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:210:27)
    at findSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45859:29)
    at processSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45790:27)
    at /Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45901:17
    at Object.forEach (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1115:30)
    at processReferencedFiles (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45899:16)
    at findSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45884:21)
    at processSourceFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45790:27)
    at processRootFile (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45694:13)
    at /Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45151:60
    at Object.forEach (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1115:30)
    at Object.createProgram (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:45151:16)
    at AotPlugin._setupOptions (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:124:28)
    at new AotPlugin (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:23:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:55:12)
    at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:70:19)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:27:37)
    at Class.run (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:37:98)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/Users/christarasovs/Desktop/dnd/dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:103:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
Chriss-iMac:dragNdrop-ng2.4.9.1 christarasovs$
```

My structure
[image]

**Tried on Windows today and here are my steps**
Here is the exact steps I tried

Comment: Do you have NPM 3 or higher ?

Comment: C:\Users\ctarasovs\Desktop\Testing>npm --version
--> I got :   4.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same configuration than you and it works, just with a difference, I am using a previous minor version of the angular packages, you use `2.4.9` so try to downgrade to `2.4.8`. It should work, if not, paste the error then.

**ADDED**

There are multiple ways of downgrading, I will mention the most comfortable for me, which is, go to `package.json`, change the versions and run `npm install`.

If you wanna make sure that is taking the newest version, before run npm install, remove the node_modules folder and that's it.

**ADDED 2**

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
        "@angular/router": "3.4.8",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.16",
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
        "animate.css": "3.5.2",
        "automapper-ts": "1.8.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.8",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
        "chart.js": "2.5.0",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.2",
        "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
        "ng2-pagination": "1.0.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.2.0",
        "signalr": "2.2.1",
        "systemjs": "0.19.39",
        "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
        "typescript": "2.2.1",
        "underscore": "1.8.3",
        "zone.js": "0.7.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/core-js": "0.9.35",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
        "@types/underscore": "1.7.36",
        "codelyzer": "3.0.0-beta.3",
        "del": "2.2.1",
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-fail": "1.0.5",
        "gulp-sass": "2.3.2",
        "gulp-zip": "3.0.2",
        "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
        "karma": "1.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
        "protractor": "4.0.13",
        "ts-node": "1.2.1",
        "tslint": "4.5.1"
    }
```

Comment: Alejandro , could you please let me know how to downgrade. can't seem to find a way.

Comment: do you have the same struture also? , I have posted an image of my structure. Can you please let me know the step you that you had run?

Comment: I just edited the answer to tell you how to downgrade. I have the same structure except ng2-dnd folder which it is really strange for me.

Comment: Could you please upload or past the packag.json file so that I do a fresh setup and run you pacakage file?

Comment: don't think it's needed but if it helps you, there you got it. Have in mind that I removed the caret symbol ^ to have those exact versions

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs because of file not found, while compiling it is looking for the file but it is not found, so it says length 0, the best solution is to add   **console.log(fileName);** inside the createSourceFile() function in the **node_modules/typescript/typescript.js** in your project and we can see which file is not present and it is easy to debug the error.

mainly because environment.ts file not found or the path inside **angular-cli.json**

Comment: At TypeScript 2.9.2 I found it in 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js'. That saved me a ton of time.

Comment: When I do that I get all the files on my project? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@angular/cli` instead of `angular-cli` :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```